# Why am I getting a "String index out of range: 53" error?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to make a Encryptor using the few basics of code we have learnt at school. I have managed to get somewhere (I think) but for some reason I seem to get this `"String index out of range: 53"` error. Can anyone tell me why?

```
public void Encryption() {
    String Password = "CodingIsHard";
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Password.length(); i++) {
        answer = Character.toString(Password.charAt(i + '5'));

    }
    System.out.println(answer);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PasswordGenerator GP = new PasswordGenerator();
    GP.Encryption();
}
```

Comment: because i + '5', no ?

Comment: NB: the single quotes make the situation even worse

Comment: `'5'` is an ASCII char with value of 0x35= 53

Answer (score 2):

`'5'` is a character, not the number five. In ASCII the character `5` has a value of 53, so when `i` is zero, you are trying to access index `0 + 53`, which is out of bounds in the string. You probably want to move the addition outside the `charAt()` parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `'5'` to the index to be retrieved by `charAt()`, change the code to:

```
public void Encryption() {
    String Password = "CodingIsHard";
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Password.length(); i++) {
        answer = Character.toString(Password.charAt(i) + '5');

    }
    System.out.println(answer);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PasswordGenerator GP = new PasswordGenerator();
    GP.Encryption();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using charAt. Your string "CodingIsHard" has only 12 letters, and the sum you are making inside your For loop can make this number go higher than the number of letters in your string. For example, if i = 10 and you sum 5, i = 15. And you don't have a position 15 in a 12 letter string! Additionally, your '5' is being considered by Java in its ASCII value, 53. Consider using an integer value (unless this is your intention).